# How to remove this Suntour Q-Loc thru axle front wheel? It does not go downwards when axis is removed

Tags: wheels, maintenance, fork

I need to remove the wheel to replace the tire. I was surprised that there are no dropouts, so I cannot just pull the wheel out as I did for my rear wheel. The lever can be released, the axis can be unscrewed and removed, but after that the wheel seems staying where it is, and also the disk brake limits what can I do with it.

I so far I did not try to unscrew anything else than axis under lever and did not apply any brute force. How to remove the wheel with the minimum disassembly? The bicycle is [Winora Youcatan](https://www.bikester.ch/winora-yucatan-12-pro-27.5-diamant-1378353_4029342.html).

I tried to google like "Thru Axles remove the wheel". In the [video](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove%20wheel%20through%20axle&oq=remove%20wheel%20throug&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i22i30j0i390l4j69i60.5884j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_84mUY7ngBKGX9u8Pv4GvsAo_27) I see the master simply pulls the wheel out downwards. But my wheel does not go out this way, it remains somehow fixed. Should I brute force to make the fork wider?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found: for this design, you do not need to unscrew the lever completely, only to release it and then the axle can be pulled out to the side of the lever. If you unscrew the lever, you remove the inner core of the axle, not the axle itself, so the wheel stays fixed where it was. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5RBYvC6FtU) is the detailed video about this axle, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuaHMtFWRS8) is another shorter.